# The LoginForm's input placeholder of react-admin2.4.2 can't change to 'Username',It is 'ra.auth.username' now.Is this a bug?

Tags: react-admin

I updated my package(react-admin) to 2.4.2, then unfortunately the LoginForm's input placeholder can't change.It is 'ra.auth.username' now. When package version is 2.4.1 , the LoginForm's input placeholder is 'Username'.
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. There is a issue if you have different versions of react-admin and ra-data-simple-rest (or another data provider).

I fixed by deleting the correspondig node_modules and installing again changing the dependencies in package.json:

```
...
"ra-data-json-server": "^2.7.0",
"ra-data-simple-rest": "^2.7.0",
"ra-ui-materialui": "^2.7.0",
"react-admin": "^2.7.0",
...
```